# Interactively change camera's focal length

Tags: 3d-view, camera

Does anyone know how can I change my camera's focal length interactively, in the 3d viewport, (while looking through the camera)? I'm not looking for the "lock camera to view" feature, just so you know! I'm looking for the real zoom of the camera change/perspective "distortion"...

[image]

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by saying "interactively"? How is that different from changing the value in the lens panel?

Comment: @Carlo There's a shortcut to change the focal length live, without touching the panel. I'd like to be able to do it. Of course you can always go to the panel, change, check if it's good, go back to the panel, change, check if it's good, specially if you're working in fullscreen mode... ;P

Comment: Thanks! Now is clear. Are you interested change the parameters while in fly mode?

Answer (score 6):

With your camera selected press <kbd>W</kbd> > Camera Lens Angle

[image]

Then move your mouse left/right.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but it's still nto what I'm looking for. I mean, what it does is exactly what I'm looking for but I know there's a shortcut that skips this "w" menu... I'm looking forward to remembering what shortcut it is! I know that I need to have the camera selected and then, press something. No menus will show up but the ability to move the lens forward and backward will be active/activated. Thanks anyways @Jerryno!

Comment: @prubini87 Then press WC, that's the direct shortcut :)

Comment: Thanks @Jerryno but that's still not it!

Comment: I suspect the question is about a Dolly-Zoom rig like this: https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/73233

Comment: Looks that @prubini87 wants to remember the shortcut but... there is no one. I think that this answer can be improved just by explaining how to add a shortcut there (right-click>Add shortcut). The "F" is free and stands for Focal Lenght.

Answer (score 1):

Right click that focal length button in the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> Properties and set up one f-curve, then in the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> *Graph Editor*, set up your desired lens shift (vertical scale) vs time (horizontal scale).

You could have a wide angle 15mm & 150mm telephoto on just 2 frames, (flipping between them with the arrow keys); or have a whole focal length transition that you play forwards (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>) or backwards (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>).

Difficult to stop that 2nd setup looping though.

It's fun to watch the (real) camera contorting lengthwise through one of the virtual cameras (<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>,<kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>,<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> etc). It's also useful for controlling the size of the fly-mode 'dock', which has a freekish dependence on the active real camera's focal length.

Answer (score 1):

When you are in camera view, click on the border to select the focal plane then right click and select Camera Lens Angle, it will interactively change the focal.

If you right click on  “Camera Lens Angle” you can add Shift + Alt as shortcut so that it call this function like for pan, zoom or orbit with MMB click.

I've made a video showing how to create a shortcurt to create interactive Focal